# MS SQL Studio 2008 Query - If I am expecting 100 results but only receive 95, what is an easy way to determine what records are missing?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have been getting requests that require me to query up to 1,000 account numbers against a several different tables.

I am looking for an easy way to determine which account numbers are not found in the tables I am querying.

For Example:

```
    select
        a.account#
        a.date
        a.amount
    from
        transactiontable as A
    where
        a.account# in ('1','2','3','4')
```

If account# 3 is not in this table, the account is not shown at all and my result will look like:

```
     Account# | Date | Amount
    --------------------------
         1    | 8/31 | $2.50
         2    | 8/31 | $7.25
         4    | 8/31 | $0.63
```

With only 4 account numbers, its easy to determine what one is missing.   With 1,000+ account numbers is can be very difficult if not impossible to find out which are missing.  I can't use a "NOT IN" clause as that will return tens of thousands of records I am not looking for.

I've experimented doing a variety of joins with a master table that has all account numbers, but have had no success.

Is there a quick way in sql studio to determine what account numbers are missing?  Or is there a way to code the query to get a result that looks more like this?

```
     Account# | Date | Amount
    --------------------------
         1    | 8/31 | $2.50
         2    | 8/31 | $7.25
         3    | NULL |  NULL
         4    | 8/31 | $0.63
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or is there a way to code the query to get a result that looks more like this?

OUTER JOIN your transaction table with your Accounts table.  SELECT your Account# from the Accounts table, and your remaining fields from your transactions table.  This will produce records for every Account, but null data for those accounts with no corresponding transactions.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work.  Use your text editor of choice to build the first section of the statement.

```
DECLARE @accountsTable TABLE (AccountId INT)
INSERT INTO @accountsTable VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO @accountsTable VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO @accountsTable VALUES (3)
INSERT INTO @accountsTable VALUES (4)

SELECT  a.AccountId, t.*
FROM    @accountsTable a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN transactionTable t ON a.AccountId = t.AccountId
```